# How do I pass variables to a function based on select value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

For the sake of this question, this is a simplified version of the problem I am having.

If I have a `<select>` in my HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Then my JS:

```
var a,b = 12;
var c1,d1,e1,
    c2,d2,e2,
    c3,d3,e3,
    c4,d4,e4,
    c5,d5,e5,
    c6,d6,e6 = // Assigned individually from loop. NOT actual code.


function myFunction(a,b,c,d,e){
  // do something with a,b,c,d,e
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  c = c+id;
  d = d+id; 
  e = e+id;
  myFunction(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

In the above code, if I select option 3, I want to pass the function variables c3, d3, e3.

How do I assign the '3' from the id to the variables passed? What is wrong with the select portion this code?

Please help. Thanks.

---

**QUESTION #2: Following on from @David's answer**

If I build an array of objects in the manner you suggest.

```
destinations = [
  {id:'123', title:'London',    lat:'1.52121' , lng:'-1.3423423', content:'a string'},
  {id:'456', title:'Paris',     lat:'1.52121' , lng:'-1.3423423', content:'a string'},
  {id:'634', title:'Amsterdam', lat:'1.52121' , lng:'-1.3423423', content:'a string'}
]
```

If I wanted then iterate through the array and create variables for GoogleMaps markers with each object, how do I

```
$.each(destinations, function(i, ob) {
  $.each(ob, function (key, value) {
    var marker[ob.id] = new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: false,
      map: map,
      icon: dotMarker,
      position: {lat: ob.lat, lng: ob.lng}
  }); 
});
```

Comment: First, I would use an array or an object to hold all those values, not all those individual variables

Comment: A more sensible data structure seems to be called for here.  `c`, `d`, and `e` seem like they form an object, and you want an array of those objects.  Then you just want the 3rd element from that array.

Comment: Something like this may be the way to go https://jsfiddle.net/otmegmnu/

Comment: quick and dirty solution: replace `c = c+id` with `eval("c = c"+ id);` :)

Comment: OK, guys. I follow what you're all saying. Thank you for the fiddle. I definitely need to do some refuctoring to objects.and thanks for the quickie @Miro - that explains that aspect to the question.

Comment: For your second question, see https://jsfiddle.net/u9hurmac/1/ , you dont need the second `.each` just remove it and the `[ob.id]' bit and your good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a more sensible data structure instead of all those individual variables.  Start with an object:

```
{
  c: '',
  d: '',
  e: ''
}
```

After all, if `c`, `d`, and `e` should be interpreted together in some way and represent something that's connected, then that sounds like an object you're trying to describe.

Then just have an array of that object:

```
var myObjects = [
    { c: '', d: '', e: '' },
    { c: '', d: '', e: '' },
    { c: '', d: '', e: '' },
    // etc.
]
```

This would conform more to what your comment suggests:

> // values assigned dynamically from loop

Then what your option values would contain is simply the *index* of the element you're looking for:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="4">5</option>
  <option value="5">6</option>
</select>
```

And you can get the element based on that index:

```
var id = $(this).val();
var myObject = myObjects[id];
myFunction(a, b, myObject.c, myObject.d, myObject.e);
```

There's *probably* more that can be done to improve things here, but the contrived nature of the example makes it semantically vague.  The point here is to put the logic into the structures you're using, rather than have complex logic to account for the lack of structures.

> "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."
>    - Eric S. Raymond, "The Cathedral and the Bazaar"

Comment: Thanks. I get what you're saying.  Much nicer. :D

Comment: Hi @David and everyone else,

A further question if you don't mind:

Comment: I've added a second question involving your answer.  Please take a look if you have a moment. See QUESTION#2 update in main question body. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many improvements to your code but if you want to use current structure then you can do something like this.

```
var a,b = 12; //note: all variables are defined in global (window) scope
var c1,d1,e1,
    c2,d2,e2,
    c3,d3,e3,
    c4,d4,e4,
    c5,d5,e5,
    c6,d6,e6 = // Assigned individually from loop. NOT actual code.

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val(); //let it be 3
  var c = window['c' + id]; //c3
  var d = window['d' + id]; //d3
  var e = window['e' + id]; //e3
  myFunction(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```